# Javascript square all element in array not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

```
function square(arr) {
   var result=[].concat(arr);
   result.forEach(function(i){
      i=i*i;
      console.log(i);
   })
   return result;
 }
var arr=[1,2,3,4];
console.log(square(arr))
```

The task is to square all elements in an array, now my output is the original array. I wonder why.

P.s. the first console.log gives me the output1;4;9;16. 
the second console.log outputs [1,2,3,4]

Comment: Look through the [standard array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). BTW, `[].concat(arr)` creates and throws away an array for no reason. If you need to copy an array, use `arr.slice()` (but -- hint! :-) -- you don't need to copy this array separately from doing the operation to create the squared values).

Comment: `forEach` does not updates your current array. It is just iterating through the entire array. Use `map` if you want to create a new array from result which contains square of all elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`forEach` is iterating the array but it is not returning anyvvalue.Use map function which will return a new array with updated result

```js
function square(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(i) {
    return i * i;
  })

}
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(square(arr))
```

If you still intend to use `forEach` push the updated values in an array and return that array

Comment: You could at least remove the pointless initial copy. :-) And maybe explain. And link to documentation. ... This is just giving a guy a fish; does nothing to help him learn to get his own fish.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a square function for a single value as callback for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting a squared array.

```js
function square(v) {
    return v * v;
}

var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(array.map(square));
```

Comment: Your answers are always impressively concise. Nice job!

Answer (score 0):

- Re-assigning that value to `i` won't update the original array.
- You don't need to concat that array, just initialize that array as empty `[]`.
- Add every square value to the new array.

```js
function square(arr) {
  var result = [];
  arr.forEach(function(i) {
    i = i * i;
    result.push(i);
  });
  return result;
}
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(square(arr))
```